# How do you pass a model from Editor for model into a controller? (using asp.net)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, editorfor

```
@model mymodelsnamespace

    @using (Html.BeginForm("MyMethodName", "MyContollerName", FormMethod.Post)) 
    {
         @Html.EditorFor(m => Model, "Submit", new { multiple = true }) 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }
```

I know the code I am going write will be close to whats above

How do I passed the updated model into MyMethodName is i can continue to manipulate it in my controller?

Please provide the signature for MyMethodName and the cshtml to give the model to the method in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add this code to your controller, it should work.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethodName (YourModel model)
{
    ... some code here.

}
```

You may find the Model-View-ViewModel pattern interesting.

Comment: Thank You, which part of my html is being passed as the parameter?  Is it m => Model   ?

Comment: Also what does new { multiple = true } do 

I could use an explanation on this line of code: 
@Html.EditorFor(m => Model, "Submit", new { multiple = true })

Comment: The method will receive a model with the values from the form set as values within it. The multiple = true passes values to the editor.